# How to pack and unpack the structure of this tcp client

Tags: c++, tcp, tcpclient, tcpserver

I need help somewhat creating, and mostly packing and unpacking, the structure to be sent back and forth between a client and server. I'm not sure I created the structure correctly, because I'm not positive the message portion is done correctly. The packet header is the `version`, `type`, and `length`, all of which are 4 bytes in size, and the `data` is a max of 10 bytes.

```
struct header {
    uint32_t version;
    uint32_t type;
    uint32_t msgLen;                        
};

struct data {
    uint32_t message;
};
    
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if(argc < 2) {
        cerr << "Error enter command line format: $ server -p 6543 -l LOGFILE" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    int port;
    port = atoi(argv[1]);

    if(port <= 1000)
    {
        cerr << "Port > 1000 required." << endl;
        return(1);
    }
    cout << "Port correct" << endl;
    // get logfile name
    char* charString = argv[2];
    string logFile(charString);

    // Create socket.
    int sockfd,newSockfd;
    if((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        cerr << "Socket error." << endl;
        return(1);
    }
    cout << "Socket Correct" << endl;
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddr,clientAddr;
    // Clear the server address structure.
    memset((void *) &serverAddr, 0, sizeof(serverAddr));
    int yes = 1;
    if (setsockopt(sockfd,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,&yes,sizeof(int)) == -1) {
        perror("setsockopt");
        exit(1);
    }
    // Set up the server address structure.
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(port);
    //create and error check bind
    if(bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr)) < 0) {
        cerr << "Bind error." << endl;
        return(1);
    }
    cout << "binding successful" << endl;
    //listen
    listen(sockfd,10);
    cout << "listening" << endl;
    unsigned int clientLen;
    unsigned int version,type;
    char* recHead,*recMsg;
    struct header h;
    struct data d;
    h.version = 1;
    h.type = 1;
    h.msgLen = 5;
    d.message = 3;
    while(1) {
        clientLen = sizeof(clientAddr);
        newSockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &clientAddr, &clientLen);
        if(newSockfd < 0) 
        {
            cerr << "Accept error." << endl;
            exit(1);
        }
        char *ip;
        ip = inet_ntoa(clientAddr.sin_addr );
        fstream outFile(logFile,std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | std::fstream::app);
        outFile << "Received connection from IP: " << ip << endl << "PORT: " << ntohs(clientAddr.sin_port) << endl;

        //recieve emessage
        recHead =recieveMsg(newSockfd,logFile);
        cout << endl << endl << recHead << endl << endl;
        recMsg = recieveMsg(newSockfd,logFile);
        string check(recHead);
        //ignore capitals
        std::transform (check.begin(), check.end(), check.begin(), ::tolower);
        string network = "network";
        string quit = "quit";
        //check for word network
        char buffer[18];
        htonHeaderData(h, d,buffer);
        if (check.find(network) != std::string::npos) { 
            cout << "ugh" << endl;
            send(newSockfd,buffer,18, 0);
        }
        if (check.find(quit) != std::string::npos) {            
            //exit the server
            close(sockfd);
            exit(1);
        }
        outFile.close();
    }

    close(sockfd);
}

//beginning functions to keep the code clean
//receive message
char* recieveMsg(int clientSock, string logFile){
    int msgSize;
    char buffer[1024]; 
    // Clear the buffer.
    memset(buffer, '\0', 1024); 

    cout << "Receiving Message" << endl;

    if((msgSize = recv(clientSock, buffer, 1023, 0)) < 0) 
    {
        cerr << "Error receiving the message." << endl;
    }
    char* msgRcv=(char*)malloc(sizeof(buffer));
    sprintf(msgRcv, "%s", buffer);
    // Clear the buffer.
    memset(buffer, '\0', 1024); 
    return msgRcv;
}

void htonHeader(struct header h, char buffer[12]) {
    uint32_t u32;
    u32 = htonl(h.version);
    memcpy(buffer+0, &u32, 4);
    u32 = htonl(h.type);
    memcpy(buffer+4, &u32, 4);
    u32 = htonl(h.msgLen);
    memcpy(buffer+8, &u32, 4);
}

void htonData(struct data d, char buffer[10]) {
    uint32_t message1;
    message1 =htonl(d.message);
    int size = sizeof(message1);
    if (size > 10){
        cout << "Message is too large" << endl;
        return;
    }
    memcpy(buffer+0, &message1, size);
}

void htonHeaderData(struct header h, struct data d, char buffer[16]) {
    htonHeader(h, buffer+0);
    htonData(d, buffer+12);
}
```

Comment: Please remove `c` from the question tags.

Comment: Please don't tag spam. C is not C++, and your code is clearly C++. Tags have relevance and meaning here, and abusing them is a quick way to get your question closed. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting, as was suggested when you created your account.

Comment: Having `recieveMsg()` allocate an array to return with `malloc()` is dangerous (because if the calling code forgets to call `free()` every time, it will leak memory), inefficient (because you're constantly allocating and freeing memory from the heap), and unecessary (since you can just have the caller declare `char buffer[1024];` on his stack and then pass `buf` in as an argument to `recieveMsg()` instead)

Comment: Also note that there is no guarantee that `recv()` will receive exactly the number of bytes that were sent by an earlier `send()` call.  i.e. you might get only the first half of one line of text, or perhaps multiple lines of text at once, and so on.  Your receiving code will need to do the appropriate buffering and parsing to reconstruct the individual lines of text reliably from the incoming byte-stream.

Answer (score 0):

`recv()` is not guaranteed to return all of the bytes you ask for.  It can return fewer bytes.  So, you need to call `recv()` in a loop until you receive all of the bytes you are expecting. The `header` is fixed in size, and presumably its `msgLen` tells you the size of the following `data`.  So you can easily know exactly how many bytes you need from `recv()`.

Also, the data from `recv()` is not a null-terminated string, but your code is treating it as if it were.

Try something more like this instead:

```
struct header {
    uint32_t version;
    uint32_t type;
    uint32_t msgLen;                        
};

struct data {
    uint32_t message;
};
    
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        cerr << "Error enter command line format: $ server -p 6543 -l LOGFILE" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    int port = atoi(argv[1]);
    if (port <= 1000)
    {
        cerr << "Port > 1000 required." << endl;
        return(1);
    }

    cout << "Port correct" << endl;

    // get logfile name
    string logFile = argv[2];

    // Create socket.
    int sockfd, newSockfd;
    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        cerr << "Socket error." << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    cout << "Socket Correct" << endl;

    sockaddr_in serverAddr, clientAddr;
    // Clear the server address structure.
    memset(&serverAddr, 0, sizeof(serverAddr));
    int yes = 1;
    if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(yes)) < 0) {
        cerr << "setsockopt error." << endl;
        close(sockfd);
        return 1;
    }

    // Set up the server address structure.
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(port);

    //create and error check bind
    if (bind(sockfd, (sockaddr*) &serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr)) < 0) {
        cerr << "Bind error." << endl;
        close(sockfd);
        return 1;
    }
    cout << "binding successful" << endl;

    //listen
    if (listen(sockfd, 10) < 0) {
        cerr << "Listen error." << endl;
        close(sockfd);
        return 1;
    }
    cout << "listening" << endl;

    socklen_t clientLen;
    header recHead;
    data recData;

    ofstream outFile(logFile, std::ofstream::app);

    while (true) {
        clientLen = sizeof(clientAddr);
        newSockfd = accept(sockfd, (sockaddr*) &clientAddr, &clientLen);
        if (newSockfd < 0) 
        {
            cerr << "Accept error." << endl;
            close(sockfd);
            return 1;
        }

        outFile << "Received connection from IP: " << inet_ntoa(clientAddr.sin_addr) << ", PORT: " << ntohs(clientAddr.sin_port) << endl;

        //receive message
        if (receiveMsg(newSockfd, recHead, recData, outFile) <= 0) {
            close(newSockfd);
            continue;
        }

        // use recHead and recData as needed...
    }

    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}

//beginning functions to keep the code clean

int receiveRaw(int sock, void *buffer, size_t bufsize){

    char *pbuffer = (char*)buffer;
    int numRead;

    while (bufsize > 0)
    {
        if ((numRead = recv(sock, pbuffer, bufsize, 0)) <= 0) 
            return numRead;
        pbuffer += numRead;
        bufsize -= numRead;
    }

    return 1;
}

int sendRaw(int sock, const void *buffer, size_t bufsize){

    const char *pbuffer = (const char*)buffer;
    int numSent;

    while (bufsize > 0)
    {
        if ((numSent = send(sock, pbuffer, bufsize, 0)) < 0) 
            return numSent;
        pbuffer += numSent;
        bufsize -= numSent;
    }

    return 0;
}

//receive header
int receiveHeader(int sock, header &h, ostream &logFile) {

    logFile << "Receiving Header" << endl;

    char buffer[12];
    int res;

    if ((res = recieveRaw(sock, buffer, 12)) <= 0)
        logFile << "Error receiving the header." << endl;
    else
        ntohHeader(buffer, h);

    return res;
}

//send header
int sendHeader(int sock, const header &h, ostream &logFile) {

    logFile << "Sending Header" << endl;

    char buffer[12];
    htonHeader(h, buffer);

    int res;
    if ((res = sendRaw(sock, buffer, 12)) < 0)
        logFile << "Error sending the header." << endl;

    return res;
}

//receive data
int receiveData(int sock, const header &h, data &d, ostream &logFile) {

    logFile << "Receiving Data" << endl;

    if (h.msgLen > 10)
    {
        logFile << "Message is too large." << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    char buffer[10];
    int res;

    if ((res = recieveRaw(sock, buffer, h.msgLen)) <= 0)
        logFile << "Error receiving the message data." << endl;
    else
        ntohData(buffer, d);

    return res;
}

//send data
int sendData(int sock, const header &h, const data &d, ostream &logFile) {

    logFile << "Sending Data" << endl;

    if (h.msgLen > 10)
    {
        logFile << "Message is too large." << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    char buffer[10];
    htonData(d, buffer);

    int res;
    if ((res = sendRaw(sock, buffer, h.msgLen)) < 0)
        logFile << "Error sending the message data." << endl;

    return res;
}

//receive message
int receiveMsg(int sock, header &h, data &d, ostream &logFile)
{
    int res;
    if ((res = receiveHeader(sock, h, logFile)) == 1)
         res = receiveData(sock, h, d, logFile);
    return res;
}

//send message
int sendMsg(int sock, const header &h, const data &d, ostream &logFile)
{
    int res;
    if ((res = sendHdr(sock, h, logFile)) == 0)
         res = sendData(sock, h, d, logFile);
    return res;
}

void htonHeader(const header &h, char buffer[12]) {
    uint32_t u32;
    u32 = htonl(h.version);
    memcpy(buffer+0, &u32, 4);
    u32 = htonl(h.type);
    memcpy(buffer+4, &u32, 4);
    u32 = htonl(h.msgLen);
    memcpy(buffer+8, &u32, 4);
}

void ntohHeader(char buffer[12], header &h) {
    uint32_t u32;
    memcpy(&u32, buffer+0, 4);
    h.version = ntohl(u32);
    memcpy(&u32, buffer+4, 4);
    h.type = ntohl(u32);
    memcpy(&u32, buffer+8, 4);
    h.msgLen = ntohl(u32);
}

void htonData(const data &d, char buffer[10]) {
    uint32_t u32 = htonl(d.message);
    memcpy(buffer+0, &u32, sizeof(u32));
}

void ntohData(char buffer[10], data &d) {
    uint32_t u32;
    memcpy(&u32, buffer+0, sizeof(u32));
    d.message = ntohl(u32);
}
```